# Postman works but Fetch doesn't.what's wrong?

Tags: ios, json, react-native, post, fetch

I'm having trouble getting information from JSON.
This is my code :

```
    fetch('http://fruitmruit.com/webservice/products/details', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        product : '145',
      }),
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log(responseJson)
      this.setState({
        loading: false,

      }, function(){

      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

}
```

And the problem is i get `status : "error"` in console.log() :

[image]

But in Postman get `status : "ok"`:

[image]

Maybe the problem is "http" in url ?
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Have you checked the type of `145` in request? But for that I think it should return with `Error:400`.

Comment: Yes i used : '145' & 145 & "145" but none of them worked

Comment: use `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` instead of `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` or else try to send raw data in app/json format and try

Comment: Try to verify your parameters in fetch with postman by clicking on Code besides the Cookies option in postman

Comment: @Vinil Prabhu , Tried this but didn't work . :(

Comment: I really don't know what is the problem with my question? Why do some people vote negatively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the body type is accepted as x-www-form-urlencoded
Put the content type

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and body as simple string
so the fetch function becomes as shown below

```
test(){
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.');
    fetch('http://fruitmruit.com/webservice/products/details', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: 
        'product=145'
      ,
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log('response>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'+ JSON.stringify(responseJson))

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'+error);
    });

}
```

Comment: Edit the answer this will work seamlessly. @MohsenSedaghatFard

Comment: Ohhh . finally you saved me, thank you very very very much @Pramod